# Tomcat 6 showing exception sometimes when start the application

Tags: java, tomcat

i got following exception in tomcat 6, after deployed war file. but its happens sometimes only. its affect anything in application ? do i need to anything for that. also please let me why its happening in my tomcat?
thanks in advance.

```
va.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: com.sun.faces.context.ExternalCon
      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
used by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl
      at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
      at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
      at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
      at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
      at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
      at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
      at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObject(StandardSession.java:1551)
      at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObjectData(StandardSession.java:994)
      at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doUnload(StandardManager.java:523)
      at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.unload(StandardManager.java:469)
      at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stop(StandardManager.java:673)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4774)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:924)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeployApps(HostConfig.java:1319)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.stop(HostConfig.java:1290)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:323)

     ... 6 more
g 31, 2017 12:30:49 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager start
VERE: Exception loading sessions from persistent storage
va.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: com.sun.faces.context.ExternalCon
      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
      at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObject(StandardSession.java:1475)
      at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObjectData(StandardSession.java:977)
      at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doLoad(StandardManager.java:394)
      at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.load(StandardManager.java:321)
      at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.start(StandardManager.java:643)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.setManager(ContainerBase.java:438)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4559)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:7
```

Comment: @Araf actually not exactly the same, thing is when i run this in eclipse it is working fine,in tomcat only sometimes showing this exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the stacktrace it looks like one of your applications stores an object in the session that cannot be persisted (serialized) through server-restarts.

You can either [configure Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/manager.html#Disable_Session_Persistence) to not persist sessions at all (or try the alternative persistence mechanism documented there) or find the application that is storing the questionable data in the session and fix it (recommended).

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. but i want to go with ur second option. can u pl explain what i need to do?

Comment: figure out what your application stores in the session. Don't store anything there that is not serializeable (like ExternalContext).

Comment: May i know why its happening in sometimes only. not all times. pl help to rectify this issue